# How do I fix a run-time error emitted by a safe function from Annex K?

Tags: c, scanf, c11

I am starting out in C and I need to write a program that outputs the ASCII character for a given integer.

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    printf("Enter an ASCII code: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &ch);

    printf("The character for %d is %c\n", ch, ch);
}
```

I am getting a run-time error saying that the variable is corrupted, however, the window pops up allowing me to input an integer, and the program gives the correct output.

How do I fix this run-time error?

Comment: Not entirely sure how to do that. I literally just started this class. I tried to use the scanf function and it spits back scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't see why the number of arguments is wrong. The type is the problem.

Comment: @uneven_mark I guess it depends on the environment. There is MS specific implementation of it and there is a one proposed in the standard, they are different.

Comment: @Eysaak The compiler is correct to warn you, however it might be less confusing to go by what you learned in class and/or the intended reading material of the course. Maybe bring up with your instructor what the warning means and how to handle it. In any case you should only use things that you know of what they do. If you don't, ask about them first.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Are you sure you are not confusing it with some other function? I don't work with anything MS, but [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) gives a similar definition as [the standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @uneven_mark Looks like you are right. I guess I confused with the usecase when passing `%c` or `%s` which is requiring and additional size parameter.

Comment: @uneven_mark: scrolling down the page linked at learn.microsoft.com, I find the example (tagged 'C'): `char c;
scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);` — you need to provide the length for this, too (because it is legitimate to write `char data[10]; scanf_s("%10c", data, 10);` as null termination is not part of the game when you read characters rather than a string.  Note too that in the MS world, the type of the length is not `size_t` but `unsigned` (one of the many key differences between Annex K and the MS archetype), so using `sizeof(data)` requires a cast.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, but I assumed we were talking about `"%d"` as used in the question. Maybe this was all a misunderstanding. Anyway good to know that there are differences.

Comment: OK — yes, with `%d` there is no length needed (@Eysaak).  So, we may be talking at cross-purposes.

Comment: Are there compilers actually implementing Annex K now? That is, when dismissing MSVC from the category "C compiler"?

Comment: Btw. this error doesn't have anything to do with C11/Annex K, etc.: see [/RTC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ch` is a variable of type `char`, but you're trying to read into it using `%d`, which is the format specifier for an `int`. That means your `scanf` writes over extra memory that it shouldn't. Change your declaration of `ch` to:

```
int ch;
```

And your program should work fine.

Comment: @Eysaak Please upvote and accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` format specifier expects an `int *` as a parameter, but you're passing in a `char *`.  Because a `char` is smaller than an `int`, the function will attempt to write more bytes than the variable can hold.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in your case causes a crash.

Either change the type of `ch` to `int`, or use the `%hhd` format specifier which expects a `char *`.

Comment: `%hhd` expects a `signed char*`: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p11

Comment: Does the MS C runtime library support the C99 length modifiers like `%hhd`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I do not think so: [no hh found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/scanf-type-field-characters?view=vs-2019) in MS.  Hmmm certainly not because it is hard to implement.

Comment: @chux: It's implemented - just not documented. The linked page is the wrong one anyways: for _length modifiers_ see [scanf Width Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/scanf-width-specification).